# iCloud setting on iPhone changed without user intervention

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have an iPhone 5s, running iOS 9.3.2.

About an hour ago, I restored my iPhone and set it up as a new iPhone.

When I signed into iCloud on my iPhone, I turned off all the features I do not use (I only use Find my iPhone and calendar/contacts syncing), and proceeded to connect my iPhone to my Macbook (early 2015 13" Pro model, running OS X 10.11.5) in order to sync the apps, music and podcasts that had been downloaded by that point in time.

After completing a sync for the first time, I checked my iCloud settings about 15 minutes after setting up iCloud on my iPhone and noticed that the Backup feature had been turned back on, even though I hadn't been back into iCloud settings and even though turned it off when I first signed in.

**Contextual information:**

- Phone was not jailbroken/has never been jailbroken.
- I definitely turned off the Backup feature the first time because I
  made sure to see that "Off" was next to the iCloud Backup option.
- I don't use the backup iPhone to iCloud feature at all.
- None of the other features that I had turned off changed back
  to On, just the backup feature.
- I had just wiped and restored my iPhone/did not use a backup when
  setting it up as new.
- My Macbook was also freshly installed (reinstalled about three hours
  before doing my iPhone).
- I'm the only person who uses this phone and no one else had touched
  it (while setting up my Macbook and iPhone, I was alone).
- This issue happened only once before - this "issue" being that I reinstalled the OSes on my Macbook and iPhone, set both of them up and then came back to see
  that one of the iCloud settings on my iPhone had changed by itself
  (in this particular instance it was Photos syncing, which I don't
  use). In the numerous times I've reinstalled my Macbook and iPhone in the past year, it hasn't happened.

So, has anyone had settings change themselves? What could explain this setting turning itself back on again? Am I just being paranoid about something malicious already being on my iPhone? Honestly, I don't have much but reinstalling my Macbook and iPhone so many times before takes a lot of time, effort and money.

Comment: My first & only thought really is... why do you think you have to keep wiping & re-installing your Mac & iPhone all the time? That's a task I do once per machine.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of happened to me. Log out of iCloud and log back in. And delete the backup using iCloud manage storage on a computer, idk why but it never works on my phone for me